# Find the joint density, given the conditional one

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Let $X$ be uniform on $[1,2]$. Conditional on $X$, $Y$ is exponential of parameter $X$. Find the joint density.
The joint density should be $f(x,u) = xe^{−xy} I_{[1,2]× [0,+inf]}(x,y)$.
I know how to get $xe^{−xy}$, but how do I know that the range of $Y$ is $[0,+inf]$, so that the support is $S(f(x,y))=[1,2]× [0,+inf]$?

Comment: An exponentially distributed random variable takes values in $[0, \infty)$ by definition.

Comment: Yes, but this is the conditional distribution of Y. Is the range of the conditional distribition always the same as that of the unconditional?

Comment: Not necessarily, but regardless of the value of $X$, $Y$ is still exponentially distributed, so the range will not change.